# Gmail: answer with different color, as in Outlook

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, I would like to intersperse my answers within the body of the message I am responding to, with all my new text appearing in some other color.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy:
1. Press the **fancy** underlined A
2. A menu of options will appear. Press the underlined A
3.A menu of colors should appear. Choose the color you wish and just click on the email body once you are done to get rid of the menu

Thats it!

A photo with the steps is here:  [Photo](http://1drv.ms/1MkUxxq)

Comment: Thanks.  I usually use Thunderbird, so I hadn't noticed this.  - -  Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to intersperse my sentences with the sentences in the email I'm responding to.